# what does rebase -i do if nothing has changed?

Tags: git-rebase

I noticed that if i do a

`git rebase -i HEAD~10`

and then don't change anything in the resulting file, some sort of rebase still gets performed.  I.e. I need to

`git push origin branch --force`

since a regular push

`git push origin branch`

would apparently lose history!

This seems to imply that some history was changed but i don't understand why.  If i didn't choose to change any commit (i.e. every commit was picked) then why did the history change and what specifically changed?

Comment: i should mention that i had to significantly lengthen this question just to meet SO's quality standards. i think it would have been fine at 1/3 the length.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it. I made a test repo with three commits. Created a local remote, pushed my branch,  and then tried `git rebase -i HEAD~2`, and successfully pushed to the remote. When I tried amending the previous commit, it did give me an error on history modification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do a `git log --format=fuller` you'll see that a commit not only tracks the author, but the committer:

```
commit 0d987988ffed315ef63f79b33eae40a8715390c9
Author:     Statichippo <example@example.com>
AuthorDate: Fri Jun 22 14:09:48 2012 -0400
Commit:     Statichippo  <example@example.com>
CommitDate: Fri Jun 22 14:09:48 2012 -0400

    a commit message
```

When you rebase, your user is listed as the new committer. Here's an example of what it would look like if I rebased that code block:

```
commit 3e23bea3c778c66h59c5f665061e9354507b379b
Author:     Statichippo <example@example.com>
AuthorDate: Fri Jun 22 14:09:48 2012 -0400
Commit:     Jacob Angel <jangel@example.com>
CommitDate: Tue Jul 3 12:39:43 2012 -0400

    a commit message
```

So what's probably happening is that you're rebasing commits that were made by another person, and it's changing the commit and CommitDate. Obviously git will see a new hash (because part of the commit's changed) and note the change.